# Which canon is Constantine: City of Demons part of?

Tags: arrowverse, constantine-city-of-demons, dc-animated-movie-universe

I have not seen *Constantine: City of Demons* yet but I heard contradictory reports that it's a part of [Arrowverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrowverse) or [DC Animated Movie Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_Animated_Movie_Universe).

In both canons Matt Ryan plays the part of Constantine. In *Arrowverse* he plays the role and in *DC Animated Movie Universe* he voices the character in *Justice League Dark*.

So is there any official final word on it? Which canon is it from?

Comment: *According to J. M. DeMatteis, the series is not a continuation of Constantine, but is in the same universe as the 2017 film Justice League Dark. He added that "time will tell" whether the show is part of the Arrowverse* - Wikipedia

Comment: @Paulie_D But arrowverse didn't mentioned anything about a earth with so many mainstream heroes yet  and I am sure they can't even make live action version of DCAMU either anytime soon

Comment: So the comment above seems likely the final word...until the Arrowverse decides otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show writer J.M. DeMatteis confirmed that *Constantine: City of Demons* is set in the same canon universe as the *[Justice League Dark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League_Dark_(film))* movie.

> Not a continuation of the series.  It IS in the same universe as the
> JL DARK movie and I guess time will tell if it's in the Arrowverse!
>
> <sub><sup>[Per Twitter - 2018](https://twitter.com/JMDeMatteis/status/979120312561356803)</sup></sub>

Since JL Dark received sequels, it follows that this continuity includes [*Justice League Dark: Apokolips War*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League_Dark:_Apokolips_War) and [*Constantine: The House of Mystery*](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Constantine:_The_House_of_Mystery) but doesn't appear to be directly connected to the Arrowverse or other DC Animated films and shows.

---

That all being said, CW head Mark Pedowitz muddied the water somewhat by suggesting that **all** of the DCAMU and animated shows (including *City of Demons*) are *somewhat* connected to each other.

> "They're all somewhat connected now to the Arrowverse for our
> purposes. We look at CW Seed as an extension," he said. "It's great to
> have Constantine. It's a great message to everybody that 'come to CW
> Seed and don't be bored.'"
>
> Berlanti and David Goyer (who executive produced the live-action
> series) have just started working on the Constantine series. Pedowitz
> said there haven't been discussions of which live action supporting
> characters may or may not be back for the new show, or how this
> version of Constantine will connect back to the live action storylines
> he's been a part of.
>
> <sub><sup>[Constantine Is Back With Matt Ryan as a CW Seed Animated Series](https://www.ign.com/articles/2017/01/08/constantine-is-back-with-matt-ryan-as-a-cw-seed-animated-series)</sup></sub>